# Socket TCP connection write failure

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have tcp communication via socket code like :

```
public void openConnection() throws Exception
{
   socket = new Socket();
   InetAddress iNet = InetAddress.getByName("server");
   InetSocketAddress sock = new InetSocketAddress(iNet, Integer.parseInt(port));
   socket.connect(sock, 0);

   out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
   in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
}
```

and send method as :

```
synchronized void send(String message)
{
 try
 {
    out.println(message);
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
    throw new RuntimeException(this.getClass() + ": Error Sending Message: "
        + message, e);
 }
}
```

This writes message on socket and communicated through tcp. (non-blocking call)

My doubt is, how can we determine if this packet was successfully sent or if dropped, what was the reason through java code?

Comment: You should build a protocol and the receiver should process and acknowledge receipt of each message.

Comment: @ShaneWealti TCP already does that.

Comment: Yeah it technically does but in practice you never see anyone build a protocol on top of TCP/IP that doesn't have its own message confirmation mechanism.

Comment: HTTP does not have its own message confirmation mechanism

Comment: @MatthewFranglen, HTTP does have useful indicators that act like message confirmation where it's useful within its context. It's a request/response protocol, so a successfully received request should generate a response (what it doesn't have is an acknowledgement of the response). It also has `Content-Length` or chunked encoding (or line return in the header) to give an indication as to how much the other party is expected to read (or whether it should time out).

Comment: The response is the result of the request not an acknowledgement of it. Equally the server does not expect to receive an acknowledgement of the receipt of the response that it sent. Compare this to TCP which provides explicit ACK messages which only relate to confirming that information has been received https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Reliable_transmission

Comment: I don't disagree, I'm just saying that in practice, you often need more than what TCP offers, which is probably what @ShaneWealti was also probably alluding to.

Answer (score 2):

TCP acknowledgement indicates that the data is pushed to the other end of the TCP/IP stack & it necessarily doesn't mean that the receiver application has processed the data. In windows/linux a successful send completion indicates the buffer is copied to the kernel mode socket buffer.
You can try setting the socket buffer to zero which makes the TCP/IP stack to complete the send call only after receiving acknowledgement for the buffer. This happens at least in windows & this behavior can't be assumed in java.

Answer (score 0):

TCP provides reliable communication with the endpoint. If there is no error then the message was received. The wikipedia page on TCP states that:

> TCP provides reliable, ordered and error-checked delivery of a stream
>   of octets between programs running on computers connected to a local
>   area network, intranet or the public Internet.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol

If the communication fails then you can inspect the specific exception that has been thrown. You should review the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) to determine the specific exceptions that are thrown and the reason for them. To help with this it is useful to be more specific with your exception handling (handle specific types of exception separately rather than just catching `Exception`).

Comment: It's quite important to understand the limits of this "reliability", though. TCP's reliability is from TCP stack to TCP stack.

Comment: One TCP endpoint communicates with another TCP endpoint. I don't really know of a situation where you could have a TCP channel that has a non-TCP endpoint. If you managed to produce that then the legitimate TCP endpoint would quickly end up transmitting and retransmitting the same data because it would believe it to be lost in transmission.

Comment: What I mean is that this reliability is just up to the TCP level, whatever is then done within the application is another matter altogether. Some people (maybe not you) misunderstand the reliability guarantees of TCP (see [this thread](http://lkml.iu.edu//hypermail/linux/kernel/0106.1/1154.html)) and expect too much.

Comment: 'If there was no error the message was received' is quite incorrect. For a start there are no messages. Secondly, an error is only reported on a subsequent read or write, for buffering and timing reasons. Therefore, thirdly, it is impossible to know on a failure what has and has not been received.